# How to change column title datagrid?

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

How to change column title datagrid ?

I need to change the caption of the columns, but I'm not getting.

The Code:

```
<List title="Todos Usuários" {...props}>
    <Datagrid>
        <TextField title="Codigo" --> not worked source="id" />
        <TextField source="name" />
        <EmailField source="email" />
    </Datagrid>
</List>
```

Comment: Please post your code trial, so we can help you

Answer (score 1):

Use `label` instead of `title`, but it is correct to use translation files to automatically get the required field labels: "Translating Resource and Field Names": https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html